# Getting an error when trying to create/check for a new directory

Tags: python, path, directory

I have some code which is meant to: create a new directory; ask the user to enter some text to put in the file; create the file; join the file name and path together and then write the text from `translated` into the file. But when I run the code below I get 
    `with open(new_file, 'a') as f:
TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Downloads\\Encrypted Messages\\hi' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>`

```
import os
import os.path
import errno

translated = str(input("Please enter your text"))
encpath = r'C:\Downloads\Encrypted Messages'

def make_sure_path_exists(encpath):
    try:
        os.makedirs(encpath)
    except OSError as exception:
        if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise

name = str(input("Please enter the name of your file "))
fullpath = os.path.join(encpath, name)
new_file = open(fullpath, 'w')
with open(new_file, 'a') as f:
    f.write(translated + '\n')
```

I have also tried

```
import os
import os.path
import errno

translated = "Hello World"
encpath = r'C:\Downloads\Encrypted Messages'

if not os.path.exists(encpath):
    os.makedirs(encpath)
name = str(input("Please enter the name of your file "))
fullpath = os.path.join(encpath, name)
new_file = open(fullpath, 'w')
with open(new_file, 'a') as f:
    f.write(translated + '\n')
```

I am using Python 3.5.0 in case you're wondering.

**EDIT:** I've renamed `encpath` to `r'C:\Downloads\EncryptedMessages'` and I get a new error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Downloads\\EncryptedMessages\\justatest'`

Comment: you can't close the file after the with statement (it is already closed, `with` finalizes by calling close on `f`, I guess this is where the error comes in?). The first code does not create the folder, as you do not call the routine you create.

Comment: Thank you and in my code, I haven't specified the extension have I?

Comment: `EncryptedMessages` or `Encrypted Messages` ?

Comment: 1) you haven't provided the _full_ error message ___always___ do that, 2) extensions are irrelevant for files.

Comment: I changed the path name as a test to `EncryptedMessages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is working for me-USE `raw_input` i am in 2.7

```
import os
import os.path
import errno

translated = "Hello World"
encpath = r'C:\Downloads\Encrypted Messages'

if not os.path.exists(encpath):
    os.makedirs(encpath)
name = str(raw_input("Please enter the name of your file "))
fullpath = os.path.join(encpath, name)
new_file = open(fullpath, 'w')
with open(fullpath, 'a') as f:
    f.write(translated + '\n')
    f.close()
```